# how to retrieve the id of an input element triggered by inline validation function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the id of input field from where the validation call is triggered,i am using posabsolute validation plugin-inline validation method.

```
<input type="text" id="username" class="validate[required,funcCall[checkinput]]"/>
<input type="text" id="age" class="validate[required,funcCall[checkinput]]"/>
```

in both above line i am using the same function name.how to get the id in jQuery.

```
//js
function checkinput()
{
  //id of the input field
}
```

Comment: You should go through documentation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin passes arguments to your function (field, rules, i, options), the first being the jQuery object of the element, so you can do:

```
function checkinput(field)
{
    //id of the input field
    console.log( field.attr('id') );
}
```

Documentation for [`funcCall`](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#funccallmethodname).